# Fund Umbrel lighting wallet with BlueWallet?

Tags: lightning-network, ln-opening-channels, ln-channel-balance-management, umbrel

Just set up Umbrel node. How does one fund the lightning wallet? Besides funding the Bitcoin Core wallet and sending to the lightning wallet.

I added BlueWallet and tried to send from there to my own lightning wallet/node but I get an API error (error 10) asking "does the receiver have enough inbound/don't have inbound capacity"?

Yeah, well I don't have any channels set up as I am trying to fund the wallet? Catch 22

thanks